# System call from Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can you call terminal calls from within Ruby?

Can i run "rake db:migrate VERSION=...." from within my Rails program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "`" quotes:

```
`rake db:migrate VERSION=....`
```

or `system`

```
system("rake db:migrate VERSION=....")
```

Also you can use this notation:

```
%x[rake db:migrate VERSION=...]
```

Also see http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the info you need: http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html