# Windows commands in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, jruby, jrubyonrails

How do I run a Windows command in an Ruby app?

I am trying to run something like:

```
output = `cd #{RAILS_ROOT}/lib && java HelloWorld #{param1} #{param2}`
```

I print the result of the line above and paste it to a command prompt in Windows and it works just fine. However, when i run app and hit this code, output is blank rather than have a string I get back from HellowWorld. In HelloWorld I do a System.out.print("helloworld")

The following:

```
output = `cmd.exe /C dir`
puts "OUTPUT #{output}"
```

Returns:

> OUTPUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue in JRuby 1.5.3 fixed in JRuby 1.5.5:
http://www.jruby.org/2010/11/10/jruby-1-5-5.html

Answer (score 1):

Backticks work fine for me. Try:

```
output = `dir`
```

to prove to yourself that it's working. At that point, your question is how to run a Java app from the command line, or why your particular app isn't work. Note that you can temporarily change the working directory like this:

```
Dir.chdir(File.join(RAILS_ROOT,'lib')) do
  output = `...`
end
```

Comment: Thanks Phrogz. I tried 'output = `dir`' to prove that it is working and it is not. I still get a blank string in output. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: @rafael Very odd; can you include your Ruby and Windows versions?

Comment: Good question. I just realized (remembered) I am using JRuby. On Windows 2003.

Comment: A bit more: JRuby on Rails app, on Tomcat 6, Java 1.6.

Comment: Issue is in JRuby1.5.3. It is fixed in JRuby 1.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `File#join` here. It will generate crossplatform path for you

> http://apidock.com/ruby/File/join/class

```
my_path = File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "lib")
output = `cd #{my_path} && java HelloWorld #{param1} #{param2}`
```

Also you can execute your system commands this way:

```
`cd #{my_path} && java HelloWorld #{param1} #{param2}`
system("cd #{my_path} && java HelloWorld #{param1} #{param2}")
%x[cd #{my_path} && java HelloWorld #{param1} #{param2}]
```

Related topic: [System call from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473192/execute-ruby-code-in-ruby-program/5473847#5473847)