# Run Linux commands "from" the 'RAILS_ROOT/config/environments/production.rb' file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, command-line

I am running Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 in a remote VPS machine running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and I would like to know if it is possible to run some related Linux folder and file permission commands "directly" stating those in the `RAILS_ROOT/config/environments/production.rb` file. If so, *how to accomplish that to set my `RAILS_ROOT/public` directory and its sub directories with `755` permissions?*

I would like to make that because I would like to automate "setting" processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
system "chmod 755 public"
```

check out: [System call from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473192/execute-ruby-code-in-ruby-program/5473847#5473847)

Answer (score 0):

You can use system command to run the OS commands. Make sure you don't face any security related issues.
Instead see if you can change the permissions while deploying the code itself.

Comment: How can should write the code, for example, in Capistrano gem recipes?