# runnig a commad in terminal is working and then runing same command by b bash script is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rubygems

```
echo how many testcases 

read s1

echo Enter the Testcases

for (( c=1; c<=$s1; c++ ))

do

read a1

a[$c]=$a1

#echo ${a[$c]}

done





for (( c=1; c<$s1; c++ ))

do

str=${a[$c]}'|'

str1=$str1$str

done

str1=$str1${a[$c]}

echo $str1

str1=\($str1\)

echo $str1

CMD="ruby final2.rb --name "\"\/test_$str1\/\"

#echo $CMD

$CMD
```

i have  the testsuite  **final2.rb**  which contains test_1 test_2 test_3 test_4 test_5 test_6 test_7 as testcases in it.

Above i have created a script that will take only the number of testcases to run like 
1 
2
5 these will be converted to the pattern  **ruby final2.rb --name "/test_(1|2|5)/"**

As we know this command runs the testcases:-
test_1 test_2 test_3 in the testsuite final2.rb.

but when executed using Bash Script the test suite runs only for a milli seconds like..
DEMO

*Loaded suite final2

Started

Finished in 0.000135 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors*

but if i write the same command **ruby final2.rb --name "/test_(1|2|5)/"**
 in termial myself the desired testcases runs and the output is

***Loaded suite final2

Started

Finished in 124.1212135 seconds.

3 tests, 6 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors***

so

runnig a commad in terminal is working and then runing same command by script is not working...

any suggestions..
help

Comment: Please edit your question using the proper formatting provided by StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

to ran system command you need to wrap it in this quotes "`":

```
`CMD="ruby final2.rb --name "\"\/test_$str1\/\"`
```

another aproaches: [System call from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473192/execute-ruby-code-in-ruby-program/5473847#5473847)

Comment: @pankaj, what not working? show what did you do and `Please edit your question using the proper formatting provided by StackOverflow. – Zabba`